# What is the best way to update atoms to minimize memory usage

Tags: clojure

I have an atom,

```
(def a (atom {:a <some-value>}))
```

and it needs to be updated continuously, what would be the most memory efficient call in the long run...?

```
(swap! a assoc :a <next-value>)
```

or

```
(swap! a (fn [_] {:a <next-value>}))
```

Intuitively, based on the talks I have heard on persistent structures, I'm thinking that the second way would be a little slower but better in the long-run... but would like a second opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The first form doesn't work.
2. Memory efficiency is irrelevant: how you get to the new value has no impact on the long-term amount of memory usage once the old value is thrown away.
3. You appear to want `reset!`, not `swap!`.
4. Consider why you're updating an atom so often, especially if you don't care about its previous value at all. You can usually accomplish something similar more easily with a purely functional approach, or at least with a `swap!` function that takes the old value into account.

Comment: oops... i meant assoc instead of merge. so in this case, reset! does do the trick. i typed the question out in a hurry so I didn't mention specifics. The atom is used to hold the global state accessible for a bunch of threads. its a big hash-map that gets updated often using the update-in method. Each thread updates a different part of the hash-map.  I wanna know if the swap! method ends up creating a big persistent tree or if it is smart enough to somehow reconfigure itself at regular intervals

Comment: @zcaudate: Seems like you are getting into premature optimization thinking.

Comment: @Ankur: optimization is quite important for me... there are potentially 50 threads updating the hash-map at a per second basis and this program is supposed to be running 24/7. Therefore, over one month, its gotta make 50 threads x 30 days x 24 hours x 3600 secs = 129 million changes to the atom. I just don't want it crashing every two weeks.

Comment: @zcaudate: I would suggest to implement a prototype and let it run for few hours and in the mean time run some kind of instrumentation on it. This will give you basic idea about how it will perform in long term. Based on that you may choose a different strategy, like breaking down the global big hash map in multiple maps wrapped in different atoms etc

Comment: @Ankur okay... results are up... so I guess the persistent trees somehow do somehow reconfigure themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Ankur's advice as well as a shameless plug for my wrapper of the sigar analytics lib https://github.com/zcaudate/sigmund I ran some quick and dirty diagnostics for update-in and reset!

#### the code:

```
(ns test-memory
  (:require [sigmund.core :as sig])
  (:import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory))

(def counter (atom 0))

(def data (atom {:data {:a 0
                        :b 0}}))

(defn update-loop [a]
  (swap! a update-in [:data :a] (fn [_] (Math/random)))
  (swap! a update-in [:data :b] (fn [_] (Math/random)))
  (swap! counter + 2)
  (recur a))

(defn update-loop1 [a]
  (reset! a  {:data {:a (Math/random)
                     :b (:b (:data @a))}})
  (reset! a  {:data {:b (Math/random)
                     :a (:a (:data @a))}})
  (swap! counter + 2)
  (recur a))

(defn print-loop [sec]
  (println "date: " (.toString (java.util.Date.)))
  (println "memory: " (/ (:resident (sig/ps-memory)) 1000000.) "MB")
  (println "counter: " @counter)
  (println "")
  (println "")
  (Thread/sleep (* 1000 sec))
  (recur sec))

(def loop1 (future (update-loop1 data)))
(def loop2 (future (update-loop1 data)))
(def loop-pr (future (print-loop 60)))
```

#### Results for the `update-in` loop:

```
date:  Tue Oct 09 21:13:06 EST 2012
memory:  152.072192 MB
counter:  0

date:  Tue Oct 09 21:15:06 EST 2012
memory:  157.904896 MB
counter:  53109426

date:  Tue Oct 09 21:18:06 EST 2012
memory:  158.007296 MB
counter:  134171090

date:  Tue Oct 09 21:21:06 EST 2012
memory:  157.896704 MB
counter:  214766350

date:  Tue Oct 09 21:23:06 EST 2012
memory:  158.011392 MB
counter:  268002504
```

As you can see, gc does kick in but the data structure is definitely growing.

#### Results for the reset loop

```
date:  Tue Oct 09 21:25:01 EST 2012
memory:  157.667328 MB
counter:  0

date:  Tue Oct 09 21:26:01 EST 2012
memory:  158.86336 MB
counter:  215137676

date:  Tue Oct 09 21:27:01 EST 2012
memory:  150.474752 MB
counter:  428276080

date:  Tue Oct 09 21:30:02 EST 2012
memory:  150.478848 MB
counter:  1052419088

date:  Tue Oct 09 21:33:02 EST 2012
memory:  150.663168 MB
counter:  1697444032

date:  Tue Oct 09 21:36:02 EST 2012
memory:  150.77376 MB
counter:  2360045388
```

reset! is slower but takes less memory.

Comment: Do not delude yourself into thinking this micro-benchmark has demonstrated a difference. Long-term memory use of the two approaches are identical, and any short-term difference you see is random luck brought on by a minuscule sample size and confirmation bias.

Comment: No, It definitely was not meant to be conclusive. The only thing it proved was the second one was slower. It would be nice to see what the persistent maps are doing underneath the covers.